# Client side Sorting with server side Pagination in Quasar

Tags: vue.js, pagination, quasar-framework, columnsorting, quasar

I have a table displaying search results with server side Pagination but when I click the columns, there is no sorting taking place and the server displays the results again for any of the column arrow clicks. Is there any way I can limit the pagination to take place only for the page arrows in the footer and then sorting to take place for the displayed results when i click the columns?

```
<q-table
  dense
  :title="Patient result"
  :data="searchResultList"
  :columns="columns"
  :pagination="serverPagination"
  row-key="name"
  :no-data-label="noDataMessage"
  :loading="loading"
  @request="request"
>

data() {
return {
  filter: '',
  columns: [
    {
      name: 'patientId',
      required: true,
      label: 'patientId',
      align: 'left',
      field: row => row.patientId,
      format: val => `${val}`,
      sortable: true,
    }
    {
      name: 'lastname', align: 'center', label: 'lastname', field: 'lastname', sortable: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'firstname', align: 'center', label: 'firstname', field: 'firstname', sortable: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'dob', align: 'center', label: 'dob', field: 'dob', sortable: true,
    },

  ],
  page: 1,
  rowsInPage: 25,
};

computed: {
serverPagination() {
  return {
    sortBy: this.paginationObject.sortBy,
    descending: this.paginationObject.descending,
    page: this.paginationObject.page,
    rowsNumber: this.patientSearchResults.count,
    rowsPerPage: this.paginationObject.rowsPerPage,
  };

paginationObject: {
sortBy: 'name',
descending: false,
page: 1,
rowsPerPage: 25,

methods: {
request(props) {
  this.$store.dispatch('patientSearch/setPaginationObject', props);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort-method`. You can write a **custom function** where you can pass the `rows`(Not all but according to pagination i.e. if the selected page is 1 the rows will be 0-5 from your array. Here I'm guessing the default visible rows will be 5.)

Check out this API reference - https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table

In QTable API, you will find the details about this method.